# My Nexus 5 got stuck when connected to PC

Tags: nexus-5

I connected my Nexus 5 with PC and was transferring pictures. Suddenly it said the device is not working.  Since then my mobile is stuck.  I can't even power it off.  What should I do now?

Comment: You should still be able to hold down the power button on your N5 for several seconds to turn it off -- even if it's stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hold `vol down` + `Power button` for few seconds and the phone will reboot to `bootloader` then you will have choice to reboot anywhere you want

Comment: The phone won't go into bootloader by pressing buttons when the N5 is turned on.

Comment: Actually that's the only way to power off a freezed Nexus 5, try the both vol `up` and `down` + `power`.